# Creating a hierarchy for shape classes within a level in Java

Tags: java, oop

I'm working on a `Java` based game where I need to model some basic shapes. The implementation I have at the moment has a lot of duplicated attributes across shapes of the same dimensions.

Example, I have an `Interactive` `Rectangle` which is involved in `Box2d` world and I have a `Background` `Rectangle` which is not involved in `Box2d` world. But both classes need a `width` and `height` defined.

Does anyone know a better way to model this data?

Current implementation ..

[image: current implementation]

Mock idea for new implementation, however `Interactive` and `Background` can only inherit from one parent.

[image: idea for new class diagram]

The reason why I have `Interactive` and `Background` classes is so I can loop through my objects like below.

```
for (Background bgShape : getLevel.getBGShapes()){

    bgShape.draw(
        gl2,
        new Vec3(
            bgShape.getPosition().x,
            bgShape.getPosition().y,
            bgShape.getPosition().z));
}

for (Body body = world.getBodyList(); body != null; body = body.getNext()) {

    Interactive iaShape = (Interactive) body.getUserData();

    iaShape.draw(
        gl2,
        new Vec3(
            body.getPosition().x,
            body.getPosition().y,
            0.0f));
}
```

Also `Interactive` class defines a number of attributes which are not present in `Background`,

```
public abstract class InteractiveShape extends Shape {

    private String bodyType;
    private float density;
    private float friction;
    private float restitution;
    private boolean fixedRotation;
    private Body body;
}
```

Comment: Why should `Interactive` and `Background` extend either `Shape` or `Rectangle`? Do they add functionalities? If not, then make marker interfaces out of them.

Comment: `Interactive` and `Background` don't add functionality. Only attributes to each type of object.

Comment: What kind of attributes?

Comment: I would probably try to look at composition instead of inheritance. You often end up with a much clearer separation of concerns. For example adding attributes without functionality makes little sense, and composition stops you from doing it.

Comment: I second the composition approach. A term for your google research would be "entity systems".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **2nd example is much better** as`Rectangle` is really a shape, but has additional data (width and height)
2. **I don't think `Iteractive` and `Background` are necessary** unless they add any additional operations (which from the picture they do not).